# Hide Login information in Account settings in Buddy Boss

Tags: customization, menus, redirect, navigation, buddypress

First time working with Buddy Boss.
I managed to customize the navigation items on the profile page, but I can't find a solution for the *Account settings* page.

What I'm trying to achieve is to hide/remove the *Login information* tab and rename the *Email preferences* to *Email notifications*.

[image]

If this is doable than we have to redirect the users from the default *Login information* tab to *Email notifications*.

This is the code that I used for the *Profile page* nav reordering:

```
  function bbg_change_profile_tab_order() {
    global $bp;

    $bp->bp_nav['profile']['position'] = 10;
    $bp->bp_nav['photos']['position'] = 20;
  }
  add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'bbg_change_profile_tab_order', 999 );
```

But I don't know how to target the *Account settings* page.